# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Tags: linux, bash

Could anyone explain to me why `echo 'test \'hi\'' > test` doesn't work? It doens't write `hi` to the file `test`. The single quotes seem to be properly escaped, aren't they?

Thanks.

Comment: See also: [BASH: Single-quotes inside of single-quoted strings by Stuart Colville](http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2007/01/30/bash-single-quotes-inside-of-single-quoted-strings/)

Comment: Is this a particular language or anything? and this would probably be a StackOverflow question..

Comment: the reason for the error: the 2nd quote ends the string starting at the 1st quote; the 3rd quote is escaped so it's just a character; and the 4th quote does not have a match to end the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can't embed single quotes within single-quoted strings.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes)  Instead, you have to place and escape the single quotes outside of the quoted string.

For example:

```
echo 'test '\''hi'\' > test
```

This writes:

- `test` from `'test '` (with one space after the word `test` - the syntax highlighting isn't reflecting that here...)
- passes `\'` to be written as a literal quote
- writes `hi` from `'hi'`.
- passes `\'` to be written as a literal quote
- results in `test 'hi'` being written to a file called `test`.

Comment: `echo "test 'hi'" > test` will also work

Comment: @glennjackman - Agreed, but it's important to understand that it can be done without switching quote types - as what would happen if you needed to display both?  These are also fundamentally different, as double quotes will allow variable substitutions to be expanded, where as single quotes will not expand them.

Comment: True, it depends on what the OP wants. But readability/maintainability needs to be considered.

Comment: Thanks. The text `hi` is normally an user-inputted variable, so that's why it with quotes (passed from PHP with `escapeshellcmd`).